# Why is the exponent operator not giving the expected result?

Tags: c, logic, exponentiation

Here is the code

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
 int a;
 printf("%d\n",(3^6));
 printf("%d",(a^a));
 return 0;
}
```

I am getting the below output on executing the above code.

```
5
0
```

Shouldn't the output be 729? 3 to the power of 6 is 729. I could not understand the logic of why it is returning 5?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `^` operator is bitwise xor. To understand why `3^6` is `5` let's look at binary representations of those values:

```
3 = 0011
6 = 0110
```

and so

```
3^6 = 0101 = 5
```

You did not initialise `a`, which means that `a^a` is [undefined behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25074180/).

---

For exponentiation you need to use `pow()`.

Comment: @David Heffernan: no UB?

Comment: @dmcr_code you mean `a^a` with no init of `a`. Not sure. Interesting.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: as far as I know using uninitialized variables in C is UB anyway

Comment: @dmcr http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25074180/is-aa-or-a-a-undefined-behaviour-if-a-is-not-initialized

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: nice to see, I triggered that question:)

Answer (score 4):

The `^` operator in C isn't for exponents : it is the **bitwise xor**.

```
00000011 (3)
xor
00000110 (6)
=
00000101 (5)
```

Use `pow()` for exponents.

And you didn't initialize `a`, so be careful with that.

Answer (score 1):

The operator `^` in C is not power - C has no builtin operator for that, only `pow` function:

```
double x = pow(3,5);
```

The operator `^` is bitwise XOR.

Answer (score 0):

```
^
```

is a operator used for XORing. include `#include<math.h>` header file and `use pow(3,6)` to evaluate power and u'll get 729